# Is it possible to run python code stored within xml cdata?

Tags: python, xml, cdata

I have a xml file that contains python code within one of the tags

```xml
    <codeBlocks><!--The codeBlocks contains specific code for this layer -->
        <codeblock name="getXYofFeature2">
        <![CDATA[
        def fun():
         print("in fun")
        ]]>
        </codeblock>        
    </codeBlocks>

    cb = y.codeBlocks.find('codeblock',{'name':'getXYofFeature2'}).text
    print(cb)
    '\n\t\t\n\t\tdef fun():\n\t\t print("in fun")\n\t\t\n\t\t'
```

I would like to run the bit of code that has the name **getXYofFeature2** within my python script. When I try and run the following

```py
>     exec(cb)
```

I get the following error message

```
exec(cb)   File "<string>", line 3
>     def fun():
>     ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Is is possible to run code stored within CDATA within an xml file? If so, what is the best way?

Comment: `exec(textwrap.dedent(cb))`

Comment: `exec()` the code still wouldn't print `"in fun"` though.  Also, depending on the source, running code directly from `xml` or other config-type files is just not a great practice.

Comment: @mzjn i've removed the first codeblock tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The following snippet outputs "in fun":

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import textwrap

XML = """
    <codeBlocks><!--The codeBlocks contains specific code for this layer -->
        <codeblock name="getXYofFeature2">
        <![CDATA[
        def fun():
         print("in fun")
        fun()
        ]]>
        </codeblock>        
    </codeBlocks>"""

codeBlocks = ET.fromstring(XML)
cb = codeBlocks.find('codeblock').text
exec(textwrap.dedent(cb))
```

Note that the `fun()` function call has been added, and that `textwrap.dedent()` is used to remove leading whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use exec() to execute any string as python code.

Just be sure indentation of the extracted string is OK.

Also make sure, that you give it the require context (perhaps some global vars or external vars)

Is it a good idea to execute python code stored in XML?

This depends on who created the XML.

If you fully trust the person who put the python code into the XML, then yes.

Or to say it otherwise.
If you would give the person who can paste python code into the XML full shell access to the machine where your python code is running without hesitation, then it is OK.

Otherwise such an approach has a huge security impact.

Please note source code could also be pickled stored in a database in a shelf file or similiar.